# how to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to get a list of externally linked objects with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to read a **word document** and get a list of **ole objects / or any exteranlly linked object** (**with VB.Net**) that is being used in that word document.. Along with that I want to replace it with my own static text.. any idea? I have already tried to use **ContentControls** but perhaps i am not using it right? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Time to resurrect the dead....

```
For Each oCtl As Shape In thisDocument.Shapes

    If oCtl.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox Then
        Msgbox("Textbox")
    ElseIf oCtl.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
        Msgbox("Embedded Object")
    ElseIf oCtl.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeTypemso.LinkedOLEObject Then
        Msgbox("Linked Object")   
    End If

Next
```

Here is a list of all the MSO shapes...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.msoshapetype.aspx